# Is there a standard macro capacity measurement of server compute power?

Tags: azure, cloud, amazon-ec2, economics

I'm trying to find a metric for measuring aggregate server capacity.  This is not intended to be a direct measure to see if application x, y or z will run on a given machine.  It is intended to be used for measuring and comparing compute capacity for large scale workloads across various public cloud vendors and / or private clouds.  It is more of an economic measurement than an engineering tool.

My belief is that it would be a measure of cpu capacity without regard to memory or storage.

A rudimentary example might look something  like:

(CPU clock speed) * (# of CPUs) * (CPU cores)

This number would most likely be expressed as hertz or some other measure of electricity but again I am going by my rudimentary example above.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done by comparing benchmark results. naturally each benchmark is evaluating the CPU in a different way, so several different benchmarks are preferable, for example single core, multi-core, etc.

Since each benchmark has a different scale it might be difficult to aggretgate into a single score. That is a question I'd ask in the stats or math stackexchange communities.